# Dynamically create JSON-api relationships in Elixir Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

We have quite a few tests where we manually put in relationships.  We do something like:

```
defp build_relationships(relationship_map, user) do
  relationship_map |> Map.put(:user, %{data: %{id: user.id}})
end
```

This works fine, but I want to make it flexible to accept any type of record (not just a user).  For reference, `user` is created with `ex-machina` as `insert(:user)`.

Is there a way to get the `type` of record that is passed in? If I could get a string that says `"user"`, I could use `String.to_atom(param)` and pass that to `Map.put` but I can't find an elegant way to do this.

The real question is how do I take a record like `user` and return an atom of `:user`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get some information about an Ecto struct using `.__struct__.__schema__/1`, for example:

```
iex(1)> %Post{}.__struct__.__schema__(:source)
"posts"
```

but since there's no 1:1 mapping from a Schema to an ExMachina factory, there are 3 possible ways I can think of:

1. Rename the factories to use the plural form, same as the name of the table, and use `.__struct__.__schema__(:source)` to get the name. This will make your factory code a bit weird to read as you'll then use `insert(:users)` to insert one user.
2. Keep using singular names but use some library to convert plural table names to singular ones, e.g. something which converts `"users"` to `"user"` and `"posts"` to `"post"`.
3. Keep a list of Schema <-> Factory name mapping, like this (or you can even move the mapping to a separate function):

   ```
   defp build_relationships(relationship_map, struct) do
     mapping = %{MyApp.User => :user, MyApp.Post => :post} # add more here
     relationship_map |> Map.put(mapping[struct.__struct__], %{data: %{id: struct.id}})
   end
   ```
4. Use `Module.split/1` to get the name of the model and use `Macro.underscore/1` to convert it to a lowercase + underscored name, and then use `String.to_existing_atom`:

   ```
   defp build_relationships(relationship_map, struct) do
     name = struct.__struct__ |> Module.split |> List.last |> Macro.underscore |> String.to_existing_atom
     relationship_map |> Map.put(name, %{data: %{id: struct.id}})
   end
   ```

   This will not work correctly if you use nested modules as the model, e.g. `MyApp.Something.User`.

I would choose 4 if all your models are at the same level of nesting, or 3, if you want to be more explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm hesitant to try the third since this project has so many contributors and I don't want to write a helper that needs to be updated later. I did try it, though and it works great!

I may go with option 2. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @sbatson5 Please see the fourth option I just added. I thought of a better way that may be better for your use.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. In case you were curious, you can see the PR implementing this here: https://github.com/code-corps/code-corps-api/pull/358/files